# Javascript Mongoose get the employees with the birthday between 2 date range

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dayjs

I want to get all of "**birthDate**" in a mongoose "profile" model that is **between** a start date (**birthDateStart**) and end date (**birthDateEnd**)

profile schema

```
{
_id:"1",
birthDate:"1990-05-02T04:00:00.000+00:00"
}
```

As you know, we check only the DAY and MONTH to see if the birthday is between START and END for a birthday and ignore the year.

for example, the birthday is 1990-05-02 (yyyy-mm-dd)
and we should find it in the range of 2023-01-01 till 2023-06-01
because 05-02 is between 01-01 and 06-01 (dd-mm)

but should not find it between 2023-01-04 and 2023-04-30
because 05-02 is not between 01-04 and 04-30 (dd-mm)

my try is not working as follow:

```
if (birthDateStart) {
const currentYear = dayjs().year();
search.birthDate = {
$gte: dayjs(birthDateStart).set('year', currentYear).toDate(),
};
}

if (birthDateEnd) {
const currentYear = dayjs().year();
search.birthDate = {
$lte: dayjs(birthDateEnd).set('year', currentYear).toDate(),
};
}
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "birthDate": 1,
      "day": {
        "$dayOfMonth": {
          "$dateFromString": {
            "dateString": "$birthDate"
          }
        }
      },
      "month": {
        "$month": {
          "$dateFromString": {
            "dateString": "$birthDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "day": {
        "$gte": 2,
        "$lte": 5
      },
      "month": {
        "$gte": 5,
        "$lte": 9
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "birthDate": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sdi-I4ZhgKq) to playground.